# How do I get dynamically updated price after selecting an option with additional value?

Tags: attributes, superattribute, dynamic-price

After selecting a attributo or super-attributo which are of options of product that may have an additional value or not, if you have additional value the price is changed automatically.

I need get the price updated after every modification of the original price.

Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: Do you need it server side or client side (so in PHP or JS)?

Comment: Anything php, js, jquery, json a way that I receive the correct value after an interaction @JonathanHussey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it using conditions and repetitions with native objects.

```
optionsPrice - price
optionsPrice.customPrices - attribute price
optionsPrice.optionPrices.config - super-attribute price
```